# Assign a css variable to an scss variable

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

Is it possible to assign a CSS variable to an SCSS variable? My problem that I need to show in comments a value but that value has a CSS variable.

```
$break: map-get($map: $breakpoints, $key: $breakpoint); // work
$cal: _return_rem($break); // work
$text-init: var(--text-rem-initial); // NOT WORK
/*  #{$break} = #{$cal} based in html font-size: // -> NOT SHOW VALUE #{$text-init}   */
```

The vars `#{$break}` `#{$cal}` display correctly, **but** the last value `#{$text-init}` Don't show it, is there any way?

Comment: you cannot ..... CSS comes after SASS and there is no CSS variable at SASS level

Comment: ok, i guess this still can't be done. I wanted to have everything controlled in variables you can manipulate with JS but with scss I just wanted to have processes.

Comment: *ok, i guess this still can't be done* --> it will always be impossible. CSS variables doesn't contain any value until they are computed and this is done only at CSS level

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok I guess I asked impossible, this topic may be left so that someone who thought the same way knows that this cannot be done